# Usb sound card Microphone with 3.5mm Jack speaker?

Tags: usb, audio

I am running Google Assistant on my Pi (and an Imp) to open my door over voice control.

My problem is that I am using a 3.5mm speaker, in connection with a mic that is connected via an external soundcard over USB. I tried to create a new asound.conf with the required input (speaker hw: 0,0 and mic hw: 1,0 (which are correct, I checked them over aplay and arecord). But even though thats the case I will only ever get input **OR** output, depending on which device I put a checkmark as standard device (on the desktop loudspeaker icon).

Comment: Have you tried with Pulse Audio? You could try this method: https://askubuntu.com/questions/555103/mpd-with-pulseaudio

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup an asym card, which tells ALSA to record through hw:1 and play through hw:0.

You can create an asym card by creating the following .asoundrc file in your home directory :

```
pcm.!default {
    type asym
    playback.pcm "plughw:0"
    capture.pcm  "plughw:1"
}
ctl.!default {
        type hw
        card 0
}
```

ALSA by default will now play through hw:0 and record through hw:1. The reason why you use plughw is to make sure both input and output can use the same audio stream specifications - even if their hardware doesn't support it.