# aplay doesn't detect usb mic

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

My usb mic "CD04" is detected by audio device setting but not with `aplay -l`.

[image: screenshot of audio device setting and aplay]

With `arecod -l` i see :

`**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: CD04 [CD04], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0`

But with `parecord` i've no sound.

I tried the mic on a laptop (Ubuntu) and it's work perfectly.

**Edit :** My asound.conf

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}
ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}
```

*Final goal is to record audio during video capture (PiCamera) in a Python script.*

Comment: This may be useful: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/71177/5538

Comment: @goldilocks thank's. I've tried to config the .asoundrc file but didn't work.

Comment: You should post that file then.  I don't know much about it but anyone who does will likely want to see it to ensure it isn't just misconfiguration.

Comment: @goldilocks I've tried with multiple conf, but i edited my question with my current asound.conf file.